# Is there a more efficient way to match keys between an object array and a map in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, loops, lookup

I have an array of objects, arr1, where each object has multiple properties. I also have a map, map2, where the keys are strings and the values can be of any type. My goal is to find the matching keys between arr1 and map2.

Here is an example of the code I currently have:

```
// Assume arr1 is an array of objects, each object having multiple properties
var arr1 = [{Alice: 1, Bob: 2}, {Alice: 2,Charlie: 3, David: 4}, {Charlie: 4,Eve: 5, Frank: 6}];
// Assume map2 is a map, with keys as strings and values of any type
var map2= new Map();
map2.set("Alice", 1);
map2.set("David", 2);
map2.set("Eve", 3);

// Original nested for loop
for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  for (var [key, value] of map2) {
    for (var name in arr1[i]) {
      if (arr1[i][name] == key) {
          arr1[i][name] = map2.get(key)
      }
    }
  }
}

// Optimized nested for loop
for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  for (var name in arr1[i]) {
    if (map2.has(name)) {
       arr1[i][name] = map2.get(name)
    }
  }
}
```

The code works as expected, but I wonder if any further optimizations can be done to improve its efficiency. Currently, I iterate over arr1 and check every property of every object against the key in map2. If a match is found, the matching key is recorded. However, the large amount of arr1 data and the number of map keys are inefficient, and I do not know if there is a better way.

Is there a more efficient approach to achieve the same result?  Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: _"My goal is to find the matching keys between arr1 and map2."_... this doesn't seem to be what you want to actually do

Comment: Typical [XYProblem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @Phil  My goal is to find the matching key between arr1 and map2, that's my goal, that doesn't change, but I need arr1 to match every item. My example is just the assignment operation, or I have more operations. Your answers just filter the same key. That's not what I needed.

Comment: All depends on the number of array objects (a), the number of map entries (b), the (average) number of keys per array object (c). For which configuration (a, b, c) do you have a performance issue?

Answer (score 2):

The iterating map keys seems more efficient since the number of keys is potentially smaller that in the array items. But you can have some optimization here: convert the map's keys to an array and use it when iterating the array items:

```js
const arr1 = [{Alice: 1, Bob: 2}, {Alice: 2,Charlie: 3, David: 4}, {Charlie: 4,Eve: 5, Frank: 6}];
const map2= new Map();
map2.set("Alice", 1);
map2.set("David", 2);
map2.set("Eve", 3);

const keys = [...map2.keys()]; // cache map keys here

arr1.forEach(item => keys.forEach(key => (key in item) && (item[key] = map2.get(key))));

console.log(arr1);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

But there's another way to improve the performance: generate a JS code to update the array:

```js
const arr1 = [{Alice: 1, Bob: 2}, {Alice: 2,Charlie: 3, David: 4}, {Charlie: 4,Eve: 5, Frank: 6}];
const map2= new Map();
map2.set("Alice", 1);
map2.set("David", 2);
map2.set("Eve", 3);

// generate an update function
const functionBody = [...map2.entries()].map(([key,val]) => `('${key}' in item) && (item['${key}'] = ${val})`).join(';');
console.log(functionBody);

const update = new Function('item', functionBody);

arr1.forEach(update);

console.log(arr1);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

And benchmark the approaches.

Here we add additional array item props and map entries(John Sam Peter Maria Alex Trevor Victory Samuel Carl Steve Bill Joe) and multiply array items by 500.

Seems the iterating map keys with caching has the same speed as iterating the array keys if the number of keys are the same.

Anyway you should iterate a smaller key array (if the map contains less entries - iterate it, otherwise iterate the array items' keys).

Without caching the speed is awfully 900x slower since every array item you fetch a new map iterator which is expensive plus using a iterator is 6.2x slower in chrome than using an array:

```
` Chrome/120
----------------------------------------------------------------
generated function      1.00x  |  x1000  251  257  294  302  310
array keys              1.23x  |  x1000  308  325  329  331  335
map keys                1.37x  |  x1000  345  354  356  357  372
OP's map keys        1191.24x  |     x1  299  301  306  314  318
----------------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```js
const chunk = [{Alice: 1, Bob: 2}, {Alice: 2,Charlie: 3, David: 4}, {Charlie: 4,Eve: 5, Frank: 6}];
const map2= new Map();
map2.set("Alice", 1);
map2.set("David", 2);
map2.set("Eve", 3);

'John Sam Peter Maria Alex Trevor Victory Samuel Carl Steve Bill Joe'
  .split(' ').forEach(name => chunk.forEach(item => (item[name] = 0, map2.set(name, 1))));
const arr1 = [];
let count = 500;
while(count--) arr1.push(...chunk);


// @benchmark OP's map keys
for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  for (var [key, value] of map2) {
    for (var name in arr1[i]) {
      if (arr1[i][name] == key) {
          arr1[i][name] = map2.get(key)
      }
    }
  }
}
arr1;

// @benchmark array keys
arr1.forEach(item => Object.keys(item).forEach(key => map2.has(key) && (item[key] = map2.get(key))));
arr1;

// @benchmark map keys
const keys = [...map2.keys()];
arr1.forEach(item => keys.forEach(key => (key in item) && (item[key] = map2.get(key))));
arr1;

// @benchmark generated function
const functionBody = [...map2.entries()].map(([key,val]) => "('"+key+"' in item) && (item['"+key+"'] = "+val + ")").join(';');
const update = new Function('item', functionBody);
arr1.forEach(update);
arr1;

function updateItemByLookup(item, map) {
  for (const key in item) {
    if (map.has(key)) {

      item[key] = map.get(key);
    }
  }
}

// @benchmark fct statement + for…of/for…in
for (const item of arr1) { updateItemByLookup(item, map2); }
arr1;

/*@end*/eval(atob('e2xldCBlPWRvY3VtZW50LmJvZHkucXVlcnlTZWxlY3Rvcigic2NyaXB0Iik7aWYoIWUubWF0Y2hlcygiW2JlbmNobWFya10iKSl7bGV0IHQ9ZG9jdW1lbnQuY3JlYXRlRWxlbWVudCgic2NyaXB0Iik7dC5zcmM9Imh0dHBzOi8vY2RuLmpzZGVsaXZyLm5ldC9naC9zaWxlbnRtYW50cmEvYmVuY2htYXJrL2xvYWRlci5qcyIsdC5kZWZlcj0hMCxkb2N1bWVudC5oZWFkLmFwcGVuZENoaWxkKHQpfX0='));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. If both arr1 and the map2 contain a large amount of data, would the execution efficiency be slow? Because I want to improve the execution efficiency. I have tested it with a large dataset of 100 items in arr1 and 35 key-value pairs in arr2, and it takes around 4-5 seconds to execute.

Comment: Oh, you have already updated your response. Currently, it is very slow in the Google Chrome browser. I have been trying to optimize this algorithm, but I couldn't think of a better approach, which is why I came here seeking help. I tried your algorithm, but the situation hasn't changed.

Comment: @BaiClassmateXiao if you cache the map2's keys the speed should be improved greatly in any case i think. have you tried that?

Comment: @BaiClassmateXiao i've probably found how to improve the speed, wait a bit

Comment: Yes, I cached it. It doesn't improve efficiency.It still takes 4-5 seconds to execute.

Comment: @BaiClassmateXiao generated an update function, improved speed for 23%

Comment: @BaiClassmateXiao anyway it seems XY problem as mentioned in the comments. it's not clear what you want achieve with that

Comment: My goal is to assign the values from map2 to the arr1 array items that have the same keys as the keys in map2.     I tried your updated method and found that the execution efficiency of the function is even slower than the previous method. The environment is in Google Chrome.

Comment: @BaiClassmateXiao it's not your goal, it's your means to solve some problem which is unknown

Comment: Well, it seems that there is no faster algorithm optimization. Thank you very much for your patient answer.

Answer (score 0):

Efficiency mostly is about finding a good balance in between performance and readability/maintainability.

Thus, the next provided example code targets readability and waits for being performance tested by Alexander's testing tool.

The code can be read almost literally ...

```
arr
  // for each array item ...
  .forEach(item => Object
    // ... get all of an item's own string based keys ..
    .keys(item)
    // ... and then, for each of an item's key ...
    .forEach(key => {
      // .... check whether a map entry
      //      does exist for this key ...
      if (map.has(key)) {

        // ... if so, assign the stored value
        //     to its related item's property.
        item[key] = map.get(key);
      }
    })
  );
```

... and could be directly transformed into ...

```
for (const item of arr) {
  for (const key in item) {
    if (map.has(key)) {

      item[key] = map.get(key);
    }
  }
}
```

... in case one makes use of [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) (iterable) and [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) (object).

Regarding performance, a combination of `for...of`/`for...in` and a function statement is the best one can get from this approach ...

```
function updateItemByLookup(item, map) {
  for (const key in item) {
    if (map.has(key)) {

      item[key] = map.get(key);
    }
  }
}
for (const item of arr) { updateItemByLookup(item, map); }
```

However, Alexander's precompiled function approach outruns any of the other solutions though.

```js
const map = new Map([
  ["Alice", 1],
  ["David", 2],
  ["Eve", 3],
]);
const arr = [{
  Alice: 1,
  Bob: 2,
}, {
  Alice: 2,
  Charlie: 3,
  David: 4,
}, {
  Charlie: 4,
  Eve: 5,
  Frank: 6,
}];
console.log({ 'before ... arr': arr });

// arr
//   .forEach(item => Object
//     .keys(item)
//     .forEach(key => {
//       if (map.has(key)) {
// 
//         item[key] = map.get(key);
//       }
//     })
//   );

// for (const item of arr) {
//   for (const key in item) {
//     if (map.has(key)) {
// 
//       item[key] = map.get(key);
//     }
//   }
// }

function updateItemByLookup(item, map) {
  for (const key in item) {
    if (map.has(key)) {

      item[key] = map.get(key);
    }
  }
}
for (const item of arr) { updateItemByLookup(item, map); }

console.log({ 'after ... arr': arr });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As Alexander said, if there is a large amount of data, the execution efficiency is slow and takes a long time.

Answer (score -3):

This is improvised Answers for your question.

```js
const arr = [{ Alice: 1, Bob: 2 }, { Alice: 2, Charlie: 3, David: 4 }, { Charlie: 4, Eve: 5, Frank: 6 }];
const updates = new Map([["Alice", 1], ["David", 2], ["Eve", 3]]);
const updateFunc = new Function('item', [...updates.entries()].map(([key, val]) => `('${key}' in item) && (item['${key}'] = ${val})`).join(';'));
arr.forEach(updateFunc);

console.log('arr',arr)
```